# Self-referencing table entities not loaded in client

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework, wcf-ria-services

I have a table `Test` with a foreign key to itself. In metadata class I have

```
[Include]
Test Test2 { get; set; }
```

In a service class:

```
 return this.ObjectContext.Test.Include("Test2")
```

I checked that data loaded correctly from database. But on a client side I see that no parent has been loaded.

I use a `DomainDataSource` to load data (Silverlight 4.0).

Someone else experienced this strange behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my mistake. The answer is to use **[Include]** attribute as always, but make sure that all participating properties are **public** in your metadata class.